# What is a commutative map?

Tags: linear-algebra

While reading a crypto paper, I stumbled on the term "Commutative map". While I intuitively understand the meaning of it, can anyone point me to its formal definition? For your reference, I quote the part of the literature below.

[image]

Comment: It means that you have the same map from $A_1$ to $B_T$ if you go via $A_T$ or $B_1$.

Comment: For a definition see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CommutativeDiagram.html

Comment: There's no map from $A_1$ to $B_T$

Comment: But commutative diagram is a collection of maps...

Comment: I think it means what is written under the diagram and that the term "commuting maps" is not so good.